# Optimal shape to cut apples for apple pie

Tags: cutting, apple-pie

I have always enjoyed a slice of apple pie... in the morning... afternoon... and after dinner. Or anytime actually. And as such, I had to learn to bake my own apple pie to satisfy my deep affinity with them.

When I bake apple pies, I make sure to use the best apples I can find. I typically always go for Honey Crisp for its sweetness/slight tang and firmness to stand up to the baking. For the longest time, I have been cutting the apple by first peeling the apple, cutting the apple into 4 pieces down the middle and coring each piece. I then cut the apple pieces into slices in the shape of the apple so I get crescent shaped slices.

I have alway had success with my pie and I'm actually quite proud of it. Recently however, I shared a slice with one of my roommates. He enjoyed it but he made a passing comment about how strange it was that I cut the apple in crescent slices(that ungrate... haha jk). That bruised my ego a bit.

So now I want know how other people cut their apples when they bake their apple pie? 
And has anyone tried the crescent shaped method and a different method and found that one worked better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've eaten plenty of apple pies with crescent slices. Nothing wrong with it at all. If you don't have any special tools, it's probably the best way to get slices that are the full length of the apple. It's probably what I'd do if I made a pie tonight.

A lot of people probably slice differently, though. In particular, if you have a [corer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00004OCIQ) (which doesn't also slice) you can peel, core, and halve the apple, then cut thin slices perpendicular to where the core was. It's easier to get thin slices this way, since you're making parallel vertical cuts. Of course, it's a pain to core a whole or half apple without a special tool.

Perhaps some people out there, especially if using very large apples, peel, quarter, core, and then slice, getting quarter-circle slices. Some people prefer small pieces; they might use a [corer/slicer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00004OCKT) to get get 8 wedges, then slice those further.

People who make a *lot* of apple pies might have a device like this [peeler/corer/slicer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001A6E91E). It does all three simultaneously, rotating the apple to peel it, pulling it across the corer, and slicing in a spiral as the apple rotates and moves horizontally. Theoretically you end up with a peeled, cored apple that's thinly spiral-sliced the whole way through. At that point you can just cut it straight down the middle, and end up with half-circle slices.

I expect your friend was simply used to one of those methods. But any kind of apple pie you can think of is being made out there. Slice them how you like!

Comment: Slice them how I want? Cool, time to make some star-shaped apple pie. Haha

Comment: This is what I do.

Comment: BTW that peeler/corer/slicer looks really intense. I would probably end up slicing off a finger.

Comment: @Jay- the blade isn't that sharp and your hand doesn't have to go anywhere near it.

Comment: @Sobachatina: They say one is more prone to have accidents with dull blades. Plus you don't know me. I am such a klutz haha I'm just glad I still own all my fingers. Also I like this answer but i typically refrain from accepting an answer until I give at least 24 hours for anyone else to add anything. If noone else has a better answer, then I'm taking this as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Jay: That's when the dull blade is on a knife, in which case you're more likely to cut in a direction you didn't mean to, and get your hand. With this, the blade doesn't move, it's almost all buried in the apple (the exposed apart is under the apple), and you're cranking at the opposite end of the thing. And I'm pretty sure it's not even sharp enough to cut if you bump against it.

Comment: The peeler/corer/slicer is WONDERFUL!  It is easy to use, and if you have more than a couple of apples, it makes it so much quicker and easier.  It's not dangerous at all.  However, it doesn't work so well on damaged apples (spots, worms, etc), and it is a bit annoying to clean.  So you need at least a couple of apples to make it worth more than just using a knife.

Answer (score 4):

Take an unpeeled and un-cored apple, and cut in half down the central core line

Place cut side down and slice thinly perpendicular to the central core line

Any seed parts will fall out if not desired

On a good variety apple the the core (the actual fruit) is perfectly edible. Especially when cooked it seems the same as the surrounding flesh (false fruit)

Coring and peeling? There is no need to waste perfectly healthy, tasty, and flavoursome parts of the fruit. Just make sure you buy good quality fruit in the first place. Peel and trim bruised fruit, and only core old apples

This method is very fast, and provides a much more interesting slice shape. If you can hang onto the apple without the initial halving you will get the nice five pointed star profile when cut this way (for extra pixie points!)

[image]

This type of slice also cook more evenly as each slice is the same thickness all the way through, and is therefore much softer to the bite

Comment: Why are flat slices optimal? I always used thicker wedges to avoid mushy-ness. If it's thinly sliced, won't it become a uniformly mushy texture?

Comment: Even cooking with a nice texture to bite, not too chunky, and not sloppy, The skin parts slim too, so they are easy to easy, and don't need to be peeled. If you overcook then they go mushy

Answer (score 2):

I peel my apples by hand (with a paring knife), cut them in half, use a melon-baller to pop out the cores and then slice them, cut side down with a mandolin, the thinner the better.

Answer (score 2):

One interesting option if you want the filling to be somewhat denser is to use staggered dice - say, 4 apples cut to 1/2" dice, 1 to 1/4", one to 1/8" or 1/16". This way, voids between the big chunks will be filled well without needing to create a lot of thickened liquid in the filling.

About the coring problem: For baking, just cutting 2 large and 2 small blocks off, leaving a square core (maybe cutting it octagonal if there is too much usable apple left), usually is perfectly adequate :)